# How to separate values into different columns in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV file and when I load it to data bricks using Pyspark, It loses its structure. I tried to delimit the same using a `pipe` and set `header = True` but nothing works out. Below is what I am facing and is only an example :

I have written the following code :

```
df = spark.read.csv(df_path, header = True, sep = "|")
```

and the result is :

```
----------------------------------
region, sub-region, country, owner
----------------------------------
new_jersey, daffodil, USA, Anker
Dubai, Bahamas, UAE, Nikon
```

All the values get inside a single column and are separated by ','.
How do I convert the same into a structured data frame?

Comment: show the data please, I doubt that the format is correct if Spark doesn't generate the columns

Comment: Sure looks to me like your delimter is a comma...

Comment: @UninformedUser Yes. That only happens when I do `display(df)`.

Comment: @akashdubey, Did you try with `df=spark.read.csv(df_path, header = True, sep = ",")` then`display(df)`..

Comment: @akashdubey I asked you to show the input data ... also it's unclear why you choose `|` as separator if your output indicates a comma `,` in the data

Comment: Show the data as you might need to preprocess it using rdd operations. Show a sample data here.

Comment: Hey. I got that sorted. I was doing df.show() and my data frame had 40 columns. I should have rather done display(df).